# jStorage not working in certain IOS safari browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, mobile-safari, jstorage

I am trying to use jStorage on my site built on jQuery Mobile. It works fine on Chrome, Firefox, Android, some versions of Mobile Safari, and on IE 10 mobile on Windows Phone 8. It gives me an 'undefined' error when I try to set any value. 
For example, `$.jStorage.set("FBID", response.authResponse.userID);`

I have this issue on iPhone 5 (Safari 6.1) and iPhone 4S (Safari 6.0)

Enabling local storage on Safari does not help.

Any ideas or suggestions you could come up with?

Comment: What versions of iOS is it working on? 4.x?

Comment: It depends on devices.. I have 2 iphones with version 4. Works on one and does not on other. Tested it on many iphone 5 mobiles, but fails on a few.. Makes me confused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue.... localStorage does not work on iOS when private browsing is switched on. When using jStorage, this causes error. Use the following if condition to ensure it does not show an error when  browsing privately..

```js
if($.jStorage.storageAvailable())
     $.jStorage.get(key);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do a web search for "iOS 5 localstorage bug" you see that it's been broken in Mobile Safari for a while. jStorage utilizes HTML5 localstorage, thus why it does not work.

Comment: It works different on each device. Like I mentioned in the question, the safari versions on both the iPhone 4 mobiles are the same. And it works in one and does not in the other. Any reason why this could happen?

Comment: Bugs are inconsistent. Not sure where exactly this bug started to appear; are they both exactly the same? (e.g., 4.3.3)